# Embedded ID mapping fails with DescriptorException: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field (EclipseLink)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the following very simple design:

[image]

A club has multiple teams, and each team having a team type code (a gender - age group code) plus an ordinal (team) number, e.g. MALE OVER 20 would be "MO20", with the ordinal number representing the 1st, 2nd etc. team for that age group. This is the PK for the `Teams`. You get the point.

Club mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Clubs")
public class Club implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club")
    private List<Team> teams;

    ...
}
```

Team mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Teams")
public class Team implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamPk embeddedId;

    @MapsId("clubId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "club_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Club club;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class TeamPk implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "club_id")
    private Integer clubId;

    @Column(name = "team_type_code")
    private String teamTypeCode;

    @Column(name = "ordinal_nbr")
    private Integer ordinalNbr;

    ...
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Teams.club_id].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.bbstatstest.i265.entity.Team --> [DatabaseTable(Teams)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:241)
    ... 182 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Teams.club_id].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.bbstatstest.i265.entity.Team --> [DatabaseTable(Teams)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:772)
    ... 180 more
```

EclipseLink complains about the column mappings for `Teams.club_id`:

```
There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Teams.club_id].
```

But why?

The embedded ID field or rather the ID class in place has `@Column` on the `clubId` field without `insertable = true, updatable = true`, so it defaults to being writable, at least that's what the docs say: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Column.html#insertable--

Hence all other `club_id` mappings must be `insertable = true, updatable = true` to be read-only, like the `Team.club` relationship.

**QUESTION**:

What's wrong here?

Note, that the whole thing works when switching the `insertable = ..., updatable = ...` between `Team.club` and `TeamPk.clubId`.

Why is EclipseLink choking here? Looks like a bug to me.

PS: I'm using EclipseLink 2.7.7. (`hibernate` tag only added to attract more attention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `@MapsId("clubId")` on the association, you're saying '`clubId` does **not** provide its own mapping. Instead, the mapping on this property here should be used to map the `clubId` property'.

This means that when persisting the entity, Eclipselink will use `Team.club`'s id to populate the `club_id` join column, and then, it will use the value of that join column, to populate the **Java property** `Team.embeddedId.clubId`, whenever the entity is fetched/refreshed. **Whatever mapping you put on `Team.embeddedId.clubId` will be ignored**.

The error comes from the fact that Eclipselink does not consider `club_id` to be mapped twice. Instead, only the mapping on `Team.club` is taken into account. Being the only mapping for a primary key property, it may not be `insertable = false, updatable = false`.

The solution is simple:

1. If you want `Team.club` to control the value of the `club_id` column, drop the `insertable = false, updatable = false`
2. Conversely, if you want `Team.embeddedId.clubId` to control `club_id`, drop `@MapsId` altogether

Comment: Is the behavior you describe anything that the JPA spec defines or is it something that EclipseLink does, e.g. historically? I cannot find that `@MapsId` behaves this way anywhere in the docs etc., see https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/MapsId.html. The docs often take sentences right from the specification. This one (while you might still be right) doesn't mention anything like what you describe.

Comment: 'Designates a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship attribute that provides the mapping for (...) an attribute within an EmbeddedId primary key' is literally what I described in the first paragraph of my answer

Comment: I really understand this just the opposite around: "`@MapsId("clubId")` tells the mapper to map this relationship to `clubId` of the embedded ID". Nothing about writability/read-only. Just the column/s. I'm having trouble with `@MapsId` ever since. Maybe you're right, just accept it as you wrote. `@MapsId` is the creepiest of all JPA annotations - or rather the first sentence in the docs.